# Problems when mapping a private property

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, private-members

I have two entity classes Project and Product with one-to-many association:

```
public class Product
{
   public string Id {get; set;}

   public virtual Project Project {get; set;}
}

public class Project
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    protected virtual List<Product> Products {get; set;}

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return Products.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public class PropertyAccessExpressions
    {
        public static Expression<Func<Project, ICollection<Product>>> Products = x => x.Products;
    }
}

public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString){}

    public DbSet<Project> Projects {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         //// project.GetProducts() fails for the following configuratin
         //modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
         //  .HasRequired(p => p.Project).WithMany(Project.PropertyAccessExpressions.Products);

         // The following is OK             
         modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
          .HasMany(Project.PropertyAccessExpressions.Products).WithRequired(p => p.Project);
    }
} 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new MyDbContext(@"data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyTestDb;integrated security=True;");
        context.Database.Delete();
        context.Database.Create();

        var project1 = new Project { Id = "ProjectId1" };
        context.Projects.Add(project1);
        context.Products.Add(new Product { Id = "ProductId1", Project = project1 });
        context.Products.Add(new Product { Id = "ProductId2", Project = project1 });
        context.SaveChanges();

        var project = context.Projects.ToList()[0];;
        var products = project.GetProducts().ToList();
        Debug.Assert(products.Count == 2);
    }
}
```

To map the protected property, I use [this solution](http://blog.cincura.net/232731-mapping-private-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-x-code-first/).

But I encountered the following problems:

1) if I configure the one-to-many association between Project and Product with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>.HasRequied(p => p.Project).WithMany(Project.PropertyAccessExpressions.Products);
```

Then the Project.GetProducts() fails and it seems the lazy loading does not work.
But if I change to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>
.HasMany(Project.PropertyAccessExpressions.Products).WithRequired(p => p.Project);
```

Then everything is OK.

2) If I change the property "Project.Products" from protected to **public**, then both of the above ways are OK.

What's wrong in this situation?

Comment: Your code is full of errors. It does not compile.

Comment: Sorry. I have pasted the whole code here. I hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Properties must be public in order for the proxies to work. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GetProducts` and just do this:

```
public virtual List<Product> Products {get; protected set;}
```

Notice the `protected` keyword on the setter. I just tried this and it worked fine for me.